# Using the .NET Simple Membership provider - but authenticating against an external service

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I would like to use the Simple Membership provider in my MVC4 application to take advantage of the features that it provides, but I would like to redirect the login method to use an external web service.

I'm having trouble even finding a starting point on line for this. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Comment: try this link http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you start with that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386424(v=vs.100).aspx